# VB.net call to API Query returns 503 but I can get query in any browser why

Tags: vb.net, http-status-code-503

Using Vb.net myWebClient call (or HttpWebResponse) to a "https://atlasserverlist.com/api/query/ ...IP.... " and I get a HTTP 503, but
if I just past the query string in any browser I get the return string no problem

Tried myWebClient call and HttpWebResponse with UserAgent etc.

```
sWebData = myWebClient.DownloadString(QryStr)
```

which returns HTTP 503

How can I get VB.net to return a string rather than a 503 error??
It should be possible because any browser returns it.

Comment: How do you know that the browser isn't getting a 503 also? Open the dev tools and look at the whole request (including url, body and headers) and compare to yours.

Comment: You should also try comparing what a browser sends for the request vs what your program does with something like Wireshark/Fiddler.

Comment: The browser displays the results on the screen, I can see it. So how do I get the string I see in VB. 
The bottom line is if the browse can show the return string what to I need to do in VB to get that string (since WebClient does not work)
Looking at Chrome Dev Tool I see no 503

Comment: Sry Wireshark/Fiddler is way outside my Scope.
Are there in VB developers that have had an API Query issue like this before.
Like querying stocks, etc...
I'm looking for a VB.net solution

Comment: MS Edge says Protocol: HTTP/2 Method: GET Result: 200 Content Type: text/plain

Comment: You should get familiar with Fiddler, it will tell you everything you need. Maybe the browser end up using http after seeing a problem with https.

Comment: Browser converts from http to https and returns string. In VB I tried both 503 returned.
It is a HTTPS connection which worked fine in past but got shut off last week.

* Looking for VB.net alternative calls to emulate browser ability to return query string * myWebClient call (or HttpWebResponse with agent failed)

Comment: That server implements the [DDoS protection by CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=iuam). It can delay the connection to up 5 seconds, in  normal conditions.

Comment: It was working last week and I can get query string from any browser. "Again" I'm looking for a VB.Net coding change that will return the string in program not 503.

Comment: Yes, you can get it with a WebBrowser becasuse WebBrowsers use Cookies. Either you use a custom `WebClient` that can use cookies, or you can use `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` or `HttpClient`.

Comment: I did try WebRequest/WebResponse, HttpClient no luck
Explain Custom WebClient, code snippet? 
I'm looking for VB.Net  coding change that will return the string in program not 503.

Comment: Tried WebClient.Headers.Set("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)") still 503

Comment: Workaround, is to bring it up in a webform and screen scrape. Sad that there are no useful VB.net solutions code snippets to extract data from an api query.